# Swift 3 migration : Cannot convert value of type [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>] to expected argument type UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>?

Tags: swift3, unsafemutablepointer

I have a little Problem with my Code after updating to Swift 3. I had this Code before the conversion:

```
            var leftChannel = [Int32]()
            var rightChannel = [Int32]()

            for index in 0...(samples.count - 1) {
                leftChannel.append(Int32(samples[index]) * 256)
                rightChannel.append(Int32(samples[index]) * 256)
            }

            var pIn:[UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>] = []

            pIn.append(&leftChannel)
            pIn.append(&rightChannel)


            //PROCESS

            ProcessFunc(&pIn)
```

ProcessFunc is a C function:

```
ProcessFunc(smplType **pIn)
```

And I converted it to this Code and in the ProcessFunc line I get an Error

> .... Cannot convert value of type '[UnsafeMutablePointer]' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer?'

Does anyone know how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should better check how your `ProcessFunc` is imported into Swift.

If you write something like this in SomeHeader.h:

```
typedef int smplType;
extern int ProcessFunc(smplType **pIn);
```

You can find these in the Generated Interface:

```
public typealias smplType = Int32
public func ProcessFunc(_ pIn: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<smplType>?>!) -> Int32
```

I assume the parameter type of `ProcessFunc` is as above -- `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<smplType>?>!`. (And `smplType` is `Int32`.)

Generally, when you want to pass an array of values through `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>`, you usually declare a variable of `Array<T>` and pass it as an inout parameter (prefix `&`).

In your case `T` is `UnsafeMutablePointer<smplType>?`, so you need to declare a variable of `Array<UnsafeMutablePointer<smplType>?>`.

So, your `pIn` should be like this:

```
var pIn:[UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>?] = []
```

---

Or, if you want to work with Swift Arrays and pointers in a safer manner, you might need to write something like this:

```
leftChannel.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { leftBP in
    rightChannel.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { rightBP in
        var pIn: [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>?] = [
            leftBP.baseAddress,
            rightBP.baseAddress
        ]
        //PROCESS

        ProcessFunc(&pIn)
    }
}
```

But, practically (don't take this as a good meaning), this may not be needed and depends on how your `ProcessFunc` works.